# Line numbering in Vim

Tags: vim

How do I enable line numbers to be displayed in Vim?

Comment: Work on your search skills. This functionality exists since the early versions of `vi`, i.e. for _decades_. There surely is some mentioning on teh Internets.

Answer (score 15):

To enable line numbering:

```
:set number
```

To disable it:

```
:set nonumber
```

Comment: short form for the same: `:set nu`  and `:set nonu`

Comment: Heck, `:se nu` and `:se nonu` if you really want to shave characters.  But `:set number` and `:set nonumber` are pretty clear, aren't they?

Answer (score 6):

And if you want it to apply to every instance of Vim you open... put `set number` in your `.vimrc` file!

Comment: Or even your .exrc file, which will work for vim, nvi, vi, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I find it extremely useful to have a binding to toggle line numbering (among other things). It can be configured as follows

```
nnoremap <Leader>gn :setl number!<CR>:setl number?<CR>
```

The first command will toggle the line numbering for the current buffer (local) and the second one will display the current value of the option on the status line.